# Getting error java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: org.quaere.dsl in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

hi i am getting this error while run this [Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389071/Create-a-Dynamic-Shelfview-in-Android?msg=4757734#xx4757734xx) on eclipse kepler as follows

```
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org.quaere.DSL
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at    com.onazifi.shelf.Library.groupbyArrayBookItem(Library.java:59)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at com.onazifi.shelf.ShelfViewActivity.onCreate(ShelfViewActivity.java:42)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-13 00:26:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(31257):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your code and full crash log?

Comment: re-check the way you are adding the library.

Comment: Please download application from that above link and I also edited my question with error log so please check it

Comment: Thanks @amitsingh I got it.Actually in this application lib folder is there so i refactor with libs folder then only i got the result.

Comment: have you included the quaere.jar file?